# Redefining proof environment without losing line break

Tags: line-breaking, amsthm

I'm trying to redefine the proof environment because I want the word "Proof" to be bold, not italic. Normally, you'd get this
[image]
with a nice line break after the proof is done. I've tried redefining it with

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent \bfseries Demonstração.}}{\qed \linebreak}
```

but the linebreak either does nothing or it makes the formatting wacky like this:

[image]
I don't get a line break on a text after the proof is done and for some reason there's kinda like a \noindent thing on the text. Also, the QED box disappears so I had to put the \qed command too. How do I fix this? I've also tried other solutions for making the "Proof" bold, but the results were even worse or didn't work at all. Just for context, Teorema = Theorem and Demonstração = Proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Give `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\proofname{\textbf{\upshape Demonstração}}}` a try. Do you employ the `babel` package? If so, with which language option?

Comment: @Mico worked beautifully, thank you! Would you mind explaining me what \AtBeginDocument and \upshape does? I've never encountered these before.

Comment: @Mico also, I do use babel with the brazilian option.

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways that let you achieve your formatting objective.

- You could run

  ```
  \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\proofname{\textbf{\upshape Demonstração}}}
  ```

  in the preamble, *after* loading the `babel` and `amsthm` packages.

  `\upshape` is the opposite of `\itshape` (and of `\slshape` too, I suppose), in that it instructs LaTeX to use upright rather than slanted lettering. The `\AtBeginDocument` wrapper tells LaTeX to defer executing the command's argument until the `document` environment starts up. The wrapper is needed as `babel`, too, defers some of its actions -- including choosing the Portuguese counterpart for the English word "Proof" -- until the `document` environment begins.
- Alternatively, you could locate the file `amsthm.sty`, open it in  text editor, find its definition of the `proof` environment, copy the code into the preamble of your document (right after loading the `amsthm` package would be best), and replace `\itshape` with `\bfseries`. (Please do *not* modify the file `amsthm.sty` directly.)

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
          \bfseries % was: \itshape
          #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
  }{%
    \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

  With this approach, you needn't mess with `\AtBeginEnvironment` directives, and you won't need to modify `\proofname`. This may come in handy if you decide to write a document in Spanish (or English!) instead of Portuguese. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I'd adopt neither suggestion.

Comment: @egreg what is wrong with them?

Comment: @antshar I didn't say they're “wrong”. But the latter is more easily managed with a patch; the former is really unpractical: suppose you want `\begin{proof}[Proof of the main theorem]`; then you have to remember the decorations you stated at the beginning.